# Magento 2.3.4 shows 404 on some resources and admin with strange url

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

I have installed Magento 2.3.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 without any issue. 
I tried with FTP and with composer but the issue is the same.
I tried with data package and without but the issue persists.
I checked the logs (magento and system but no luck)

I tried several recent answers here with no luck either. 
My issue is:
the store is accessible but I get 404 on css and images

The admin is accessible doing /index.php/ instead of / (that's the smallest issue so far) but no css and images.

If from the admin I go to the setup to install new packages I see properly css and images.

Functionalities seem to work properly.

How can I solve?

Edit: If I inspect one resource that is not loaded I see that the url it is trying to solve is:

```
https://store.aaa.com/pub/static/version1588064406/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Dotdigitalgroup_Email/js/fancyBoxInit.js
```

but looking in the folder I see that the correct path is

```
pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Dotdigitalgroup_Email/js/fancyBoxInit.js
```

in static there is a version.txt folder with an entry for 1588064406 but not such folder

Comment: any error showing in console  ???

Comment: Nothing relevant. The only error I see overall is on the system.log about the memory usage for the temporary table but no error are raised when I try to access the page. On the server side no errors either

Comment: you use live server and move project other server ???

Comment: no. I just downloaded the magento version with sample data and installed it with the installer. Installer went fine but now I have this where the installation guide says I should see the home and admin page

Answer (score 0):

First try cleaning cookies then try the following commands

```
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

also to get a better understanding of what might be wrong, turn on the developer mode by executing the command

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

and you can check for any errors inside var/log folder!

Comment: There are no errors in the logs as I said in the question. But I will give your advice a try. Thanks!

Comment: check magento logs, not server logs

Comment: run al the commands you suggested. ended up all successful but again with a 404 error

Comment: create .htaccess file on the root of your site and insert the contents of this file there
https://github.com/magento-2/magento-2-community-sample-data/blob/master/.htaccess.sample

Comment: As stated in the question it is there